# Codeigniter : passing radio value to database

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, radio-button

I want to make a simple exams system.

The idea is to ask a question from the form below, then send values with the data below so I want to send the checked input to column named right answer and send the both to a column named choices.

Any ideas ?

I have this form in the view

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('home') ;?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="Enter question here"><br>
    <label>choose the right answer</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="first"> <input type="text" placeholder="first choice"><br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="second" checked><input type="text" placeholder="second choice"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="sumbit" name="ask">
</form>
```

This is my controller :

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('exams_model') ;
    }
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('vieww') ;
        if($this->input->post('ask')) {
            $this->exams_model->add_question() ;
        }
    }

}
```

& this is the model :

```
class Exams_model extends CI_Model{
    public function add_question(){
        $data = array(
            'question' => $this->input->post('question') ,
            'choices' => $this->input->post('#') , // here i want to send both inputs ( the checked and non checked input
            'right_answer' => $this->input->post('#') // i want to pass the checked input to  the column right answer in the database 


        );
        $insert = $this->db->insert('exams' , $data);
        return $insert ;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot send the unchecked values of a radio button.
 
But what you can do is:
 Create hidden fields naming them as choice_1 and choice_2, 
set them the same value you set to the radio button options.

```
<input type="hidden" name='choice_1' value='first_value'/> 
<input type="hidden" name='choice_2' value='second_value'/>

<input type="radio" name='answer' value='first_value'/> 
<input type="radio" name='answer' value='second_value'/>
```

Now get their corresponding values in your model as you did before.

```
 $data = array(
        'question' => $this->input->post('question') ,
        'choices' => $this->input->post('choice_1').' and '.$this->input->post('choice_2') , 
        'right_answer' => $this->input->post('#') 
    );
```

Vote up if found helpful :-)